# dispatch_barrier_async doesn't wait for CoreImage to finish with processing

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, core-image, dispatch-async

before I ask my question I should say I have read so much about it and I've tried so many ways but none has worked. I'm doing dozens of Core Image processing in a concurrent Queue, and I need to wait for them by using a dispatch_barrier_async to finish so only then I can do my final render and go to the next view controller but ironically, dispatch_barrier doesn't wait for my concurrent queue to finish, Why is that? is it because Im doing core image processing in the wrong thread?

//Here is my cocurrent queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = 
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
```

Using it for processing effects here as an example

```
-(void)setupEffects{
//It's one of my effects as an example which renders for previewing the //effect.

case Effect4:{
              dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                  //BG
                  self.firstCIFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHexagonalPixellate"
                                            withInputParameters:@{@"inputImage": [self getFirstCIImage],@"inputScale":@26}];
                  self.lastSelectedInputImgforBG =[self applyCIEffectWithCrop];

                  //FG
                  self.firstCIFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectProcess"
                                            withInputParameters:@{@"inputImage":[self getFirstCIImage]}];
                  self.fgImgWithEffect = [self applyCIEffect];

                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      self.lastSelectedInputImgforFG= [self cropAndFadeAndRenderFGImage];
                      [self saveEffect];
                      [self loadEffectsWithIndex:effectIndex];
                  });
              });
 }

//Once user is done, it renders the image once again
-(UIImage *)applyCIEffectWithCrop{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    @autoreleasepool{
        weakSelf.firstCIContext =nil;
        weakSelf.firstResultCIImage=nil;
        weakSelf.croppingCIImage=nil;

        weakSelf.firstCIContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        weakSelf.firstResultCIImage = [weakSelf.firstCIFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
        weakSelf.croppingCIImage=[weakSelf.firstResultCIImage imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0,0, weakSelf.affineClampImage1.size.width*scale , weakSelf.affineClampImage1.size.height*scale)];
        return  [UIImage imageFromCIImage:weakSelf.croppingCIImage scale:1.0 orientation:weakSelf.scaledDownInputImage.imageOrientation cropped:YES withFirstCIImage:[weakSelf getFirstCIImage]];
    }
}
```

And then for my final render, this method needs to wait for my setupEffect to finish and then use the segue but it doesn't.

```
- (void)doneButtonAction {
    _finalRender =YES;
    CGFloat max=MAX(self.originalSizeInputImage.size.width,self.originalSizeInputImage.size.height);
    if (max<=1700){
        //Do nothing for Final Render
        self.scaledDownInputImage= self.originalSizeInputImage;
    }else{
        CGSize scaledDownSize = [self getScalingSizeForFinalRenderForImage: self.originalSizeInputImage];
        self.scaledDownInputImage = [self scaleThisImage:self.originalSizeInputImage scaledToFillSize:scaledDownSize];
    }
    imageRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.scaledDownInputImage.size, self.viewWithLoadedImages.bounds);

    //Preparation for high quality render with high resolution input 
    //image.
    self.affineClampImage1 = [self affineClampImage];
    self.selectionCropAndBlurredImage = [self croppedFGtoGetBlurred];
    [self.imgData appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.scaledDownInputImage)];
    [self.effectClass getimageWithImageData:self.imgData];

    if (_effectMode) {
        //Applying effects again for the high resolution input image.
        [self setupEffects];
    }else{
        [self setupFilters];
    }

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        //Rendering the high quality Images in full resolution here.
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,
                                  self.lastSelectedInputImgforBG.size.width  *self.lastSelectedInputImgforBG.scale,
                                  self.lastSelectedInputImgforBG.size.height *self.lastSelectedInputImgforBG.scale);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, 1.0);
        // Draw transparent images on top of each other
        [self.lastSelectedInputImgforBG drawInRect:frame];
        [self.lastSelectedInputImgforFG drawInRect:frame];
        self.tempImage=nil;
        self.tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    });

    dispatch_barrier_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        // Getting the full resolution rendered image and going to 
        //the next viewcontroller when the setupEffect and render is 
        //finished... which it doesn't wait until they're finished...
        self.finalHightqualityRenderedImage = self.tempImage;        
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showShareVC" sender:self];
    });
}
```

I should mention My code works without problem without using my concurrent queue but of course that blocks the UI until its done which is not my goal. 
Your help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the explanation is at the bottom of the [dispatch_barrier_async](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452797-dispatch_barrier_async):

> The queue you specify should be a concurrent queue that you create yourself using the dispatch_queue_create function. If the queue you pass to this function is a serial queue or one of the global concurrent queues, this function behaves like the dispatch_async function.

So instead of grabbing `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` as per your
 first line of code, create `concurrentQueue` yourself using `dispatch_queue_create`.

Comment: Like this? `dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);` Will it be concurrent if I define it like this?

Comment: Okay I tried doing this which I assume Is  what you are suggesting      `concurrentQueue =dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);`  and nope, the problem still exists, it didn't make any difference unfortunately. @Clafou

Comment: I referenced the wrong function--edited my answer now to correct it. May I ask why you are using dispatch_async for the block that you commented as "Rendering the high quality Images in full resolution here", and not dispatch_barrier_async? Sounds like that is the block that needs to wait for the other blocks to complete? Also confused by your last block as all it does is UI, so it should be on the main thread.

Comment: that "rendering in full resolution" is a  part of the code that needs to wait for "setupEffect" and then "[self loadEffectsWithIndex:effectIndex]" to be finished so it can be executed and after all of these are finished, the performSegueWithIdentifier should be called... So you suggest the full resolution render part is the part of the code that needs to be in async_barrier?!? I thought the part of the code that needs to run last (segue) needs to be in async_barrier!!? @Clafou

Comment: Yes, if it needs to wait then it needs to be the one in dispatch_barrier_async, which makes it wait.

Comment: So what about the segue since its the last thijg I want to be executed? I should perform the segue also in the barrier after the full resolution render ... right? Im sorry for asking obvious questions since its a bit confusing for me.

Comment: But you don't want that executed on your rendering queue, you want it on the main thread. So just add it at the end of your rendering block inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() block.

Comment: It's just really strange ..... I can show the results here...              `Done Action 
1  --> affineClampImage
2  --> croppedFGtoGetBlurred
3  --> setupEffects called
4  --> Effect4 Started
5  --> applyCIEffectWithCrop
6  --> applyCIEffect
7  --> cropAndFadeAndRenderFGImage
12 —-> after SetupEffects inside dispatch_barrier_async, Start full resolution render  
8  --> Save EFFECTS
9  --> loadEffectsWithIndex: 3
13 --> full resolution render finished with size: {1732, 2612}
10 --> edited FG  size: {603, 909}
11 --> edited BG size: {1732, 2612}
14 --> ShareVC: viewDidLoad` @Clafou

Comment: They should be executed in the order from 1 to 14, the strange point is that yes in Effect4, i'm calling cropAndFadeAndRenderFGImage & Save EFFECTS & loadEffectsWithIndex: in main thread but WHY it comes out of order and before SaveEffect Is continues from main thread in My doneAction Method? shouldn't it execute the functions in main thread in the order I call them? @Clafou

Comment: It's a concurrent queue, so they can be executed simultaneously. I think it may make more sense to use a serial queue (executing one after the other)?

Comment: I know but what im saying is that the actions in main thread are supposed to be executed in order... Since they're not connected to the tasks which are in concurrent queue, isn't that how it should be? But in my case its not, it jumps out of "cropAndFadeAndRenderFGImage" to the async_barrier even tho it Should call saveEffect and the rest of methods which are in main Thread first :( ugh It kills @Clafou

Comment: I don't understand everything here. If I were in your shoes I'd work on paper (drawing a sequence diagram) and maybe clearly separate the UI code for the main queue with the background queue code, and also change to a serial queue ( `concurrentQueue =dispatch_queue_create("My Queue" (DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)` ) to simplify it and eliminate the barrier. Good luck!